# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe318e825f0'

Tags: xcode

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
       //array with image filenames and country names
        _paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png"   inDirectory:self.itemName];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.itemName);
        _country=_paths;
        for(int i=0;i <[_paths count];i++)
        {
            NSString *append=[_paths objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *temp= [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[ append     componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]];
             NSString *temp1= [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[ append componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]];
            [_paths replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:temp];
            [_country replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:temp1];


        }

    // Connect data
       self.myPickerView.dataSource = self;
        self.myPickerView.delegate = self;
        self.maxIndex = [_country count];
        self.displayedFlagIndex = arc4random() % self.maxIndex;
    [self.ImageItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: _paths[self.displayedFlagIndex]]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandler:)];
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;           // set appropriate GR attributes
    self.ImageItem.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.ImageItem addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];  // add GR to view


    self.myTextield.delegate=(id)self;


    }


    // set image displayed based on item selected
   // self.itemImage.image = [images objectAtIndex:self.itemNumber];


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void) tapHandler: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

    _myTextield.text=@"";
    NSLog(@"in tapHandler");
    self.displayedFlagIndex = arc4random() % self.maxIndex;
    [self.ImageItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: _paths[self.displayedFlagIndex]]];
}
```

I am trying to implement navigation controller with a table view and view controllers. Will post more code if required.
I have checked that the tapRecognizer method calls the tapHandler: method and not any other. But it still throws the exception of unrecognized selector sent to the instance.
-Thanks!

Comment: Don't show a screen shot of your code. Copy/paste it. Show the whole error message.

Comment: 2015-10-22 07:24:20.798 MultiMVC[5500:262274] Transition via segue: 'transitionToImage'
2015-10-22 07:24:20.826 MultiMVC[5500:262274] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x7fe673c2d200> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DetailView.'

Comment: Check the outlet in `DetailViewController `, `DetailView` seems to be linked, where it shouldn't be, or reverse.

Comment: DetailView doesnt refer to anything in the story board

Comment: Did you have before a IBoutlet called `DetailView`?

Comment: No. This is the error message it throws 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd563f3a140'

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `_paths[self.displayedFlagIndex]` returns a `NSArray` (with one object) object whereas you expect a `NSString` for `imageNamed:` method of `UIImage`.

That's why you're getting the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd563f3a140'

The origin of your issue:

```
NSString *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[append componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]];
NSString *temp1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[append componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]];
```

This should clearly throw a warning saying that's you can mix like that `NSString` and `NSArray`

You should do this instead:

```
NSString *temp = [[append componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
NSString *temp1 = [[append componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject];
```